# Field defines a relation with model 'Division', which is either not installed, or is abstract. Django

Tags: python, django

I have Error:
polls.Choice.division_names: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Division', which is either not installed, or is abstract

models.py

````
    division_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    division_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.division_name

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'db'
        db_table = "divisions"


class Choice(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    funny_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    division_names = models.ForeignKey(Division, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.funny_name```
````

Comment: That does not appear to be the complete models.py, is it?

Comment: Yes, not all...

Comment: At least show the full definition of the `Division` class.

Comment: `class Division(models.Model):
    division_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    division_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.division_name

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'db'
        db_table = "divisions" `

Comment: Edit your initial question to show the Division class definition there - the comment is not as readable.

Any reason why you need to set `app_label` on `Division` explicitly? Which app is the Choice model defined in?